# Reactive Power (negative P)

Tags: ac

"During the interval that p is negative, power is being returned to the load. (This can only happen if the load contains reactive elements"

Can someone explain to me why this is the only case P can only be negative. (Please provide a practical application for the idea behind it).

Referance https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbGdM.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have transcribed your quote incorrectly. It says "power is being returned from the load". What you have said in your question is nonsense. The actual text is describing situations when the load is a reactive component. Under these circumstances current and voltage may be up to 90 degrees different in phase and if you multiplied the voltage and current you would see both negative and positive sections of power.

Note that if the phase angle is exactly 90 degrees (perfect C or L) the positive power and negative power are exactly equal meaning average power is zero: -

[image]

Scenario 1 is a resistive load and scenario 3 is a purely reactive load (an inductor as it happens)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the only case that p can be negative. If my load is a battery and my source is a resistor, p will always be negative.

In context of AC circuits:
To be perfectly clear, no configuration of ideal resistors will ever result in reactive power. Never.